# How to append one dataframe to another dataframe without duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to append one data frame with another data frame, but every 
time I run the script it is keep appending the same row multiple times, but it 
should not append the same dataframe in multiple times, need some suggestions 
on this?

```
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import timedelta
    import glob
    directory1= r'path'
    files=glob.glob(directory1 + "\*.xls")
    for file in files:
       df= pd.read_excel(file,index_col=None, header=0)
    df1 = df[:-1]
    Average=df1['amount'].mean()
    Median=df1['amount'].median()
    val=20
    target=pd.read_excel('path\file.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
    date=target.iloc[1]
    df05= date['Week']+timedelta(days=7)
    sa=pd.Series([df05,Average,Median,val],index=['Week(Sunday)','Average 
    Amount','Median','Target'])
     target=target.append(sa,ignore_index=True,verify_integrity=True)
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter('path\file.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
    target.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: oy vey, please fix the formatting

Comment: its, done now.. thanks a lot

Comment: "for file in files:
       df= pd.read_excel(file,index_col=None, header=0)"

This structure is very weird, after the for loop is finished, only the final file will be in df.  Nothing else is done in this for loop.  Are you sure indentation is correct here?

Comment: You mean the indentation at df1 = d[:-1]?

Comment: yes, if you want to do something with every file, you need to ident everything below the for loop.  the way it is now, it only reads file, reads next file and so on.  replacing the content of the df variable.

Comment: ok, till which line of the code I have to bring into the for loop, I tried till target=target.append under for loop, the next line (writer=pd) is comes out of for loop, but still it is keeping appending the same rows multiple times

Comment: presumably u should move the read_excel of the target before the for loop, and keep everything until append inside.

Comment: you mean target=pd.read_excel('path\file.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1') this line before the for loop and all remaining until append before writerr should be under for loop right?

Comment: yeah, but im going to bed now.  good luck man.  Try to think about why some things have to be kept out of the loop and why some things have to be in it.

Comment: sure, thanks for the inputs

Comment: still, the issue persists, it is appending multiple times

Comment: it is working fine, am trying to merge two variable in for loop , but am getting an error for this line  for "file,file2 in files,files2:" in this line am getting one error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) , how to handle this